# Spawn object on real world coordinates (Mapbox + Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I would like to spawn object in Unity map at the point of real world coordinates provided by Mapbox. I would like some advice where to start.

Comment: Have you checked out the GeoToWorldPosition method? [Link to docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-unity-sdk/api/unity/Mapbox.Unity.Utilities.Conversions.html)

Comment: Yes, this is good but I dont understand how to get data to use it with Unity.   I have code where I spawn object on map: spawnObject = Instantiate(Object[randomObjects], new Vector3(randomX, Map.position.y + 5, Map.position.z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

Comment: It would maybe help to see your complete code

Comment: I have tried with SpawnOnMap script and now it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also upload your data to Mapbox, and specify it as data source in the AbstractMap.cs script.